# Sum of a column in 1 table group by 2 other columns in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables, the 1st one is

outcomes

```
ssn,date,scode,dcode,ppay,ipay
302609074,20180215,4002,1001,25,35
302609074,20180215,4006,1003,40,100
302609074,20181010,4002,1001,25,35
302609074,20181010,4006,1003,40,100
302609074,20190505,4002,1001,25,35
302609074,20190506,4006,1003,40,100
997600970,20190115,4001,1002,25,50
997600970,20190115,4001,1003,40,30
997600970,20190115,4004,1004,40,50
997600970,20190415,4002,1004,40,95
997600970,20190415,4003,1005,40,100
997600970,20181212,4004,1001,25,47
997600970,20181213,4004,1001,25,47
874136439,20190808,4002,1002,25,50
874136439,20190808,4002,1003,40,60
874136439,20190910,4002,1004,40,95
874136439,20190910,4002,1005,60,90
874136439,20191001,4003,1002,25,50
874136439,20191002,4003,1002,25,50
874136439,20191003,4003,1002,25,55
831287780,20190404,4001,1001,25,0
831287780,20190505,4003,1002,25,40
831287780,20190606,4004,1003,25,100
831287780,20190707,4006,1004,60,100
882861510,20190202,4005,1002,60,60
882861510,20190303,4002,1004,25,100
882861510,20190404,4005,1002,40,100
882861510,20190505,4002,1004,50,100
882861510,20190606,4005,1003,50,0
796235486,20190808,4001,1001,25,25
445139565,20180707,4002,1001,40,35
445139565,20190929,4002,1003,40,70
445139565,20190929,4002,1004,40,95
445139565,20190929,4002,1005,40,120
524246868,20190909,4006,1005,100,100
524246868,20190910,4006,1005,100,100
416806352,20190818,4003,1001,25,30
416806352,20190818,4003,1005,50,100
946883650,20190717,4001,1004,25,100
946883650,20190817,4001,1004,25,100
946883650,20190917,4006,1004,50,132
946883650,20191002,4006,1004,50,132
129141378,20190909,4001,1002,25,50
129141378,20190909,4001,1003,0,100
129141378,20190909,4001,1004,0,125
129141378,20190909,4001,1005,0,150
950022926,20181111,4006,1004,182,0
950022926,20190323,4006,1004,100,82
950022926,20190623,4006,1004,0,182
799023031,20190930,4005,1003,50,100
719301054,20190110,4001,1003,25,75
719301054,20190210,4001,1003,25,75
719301054,20190310,4001,1003,25,75
316517393,20190626,4005,1005,0,0
148694321,20190102,4006,1002,40,72
148694321,20190203,4006,1002,40,72
148694321,20190304,4006,1002,40,72
332124842,20190405,4004,1001,25,47
332124842,20190506,4004,1002,25,80
332124842,20190607,4004,1003,25,107
```

and
diagnosis

scode,dcode,charge

4001,1001,50

4001,1002,75

4001,1003,100

4001,1004,125

4001,1005,150

4002,1001,60

4002,1002,85

4002,1003,110

4002,1004,135

4002,1005,160

4003,1001,55

4003,1002,80

4003,1003,105

4003,1004,130

4003,1005,155

4004,1001,72

4004,1002,102

4004,1003,132

4004,1004,162

4004,1005,192

4005,1001,90

4005,1002,140

4005,1003,190

4005,1004,240

4005,1005,290

4006,1001,77

4006,1002,112

4006,1003,147

4006,1004,182

4006,1005,217

I need to get the SUM(charge) for each SSN on the same date.  For example from

```
302609074,20180215,4002,1001,25,35
302609074,20180215,4006,1003,40,100
```

I want to get the sum(charge) = 60 + 147 = 207 from table diagnosis, on date 20180215

Nothing I've tried has worked so far.  For example, I got:

```
ELECT Z.date, Z.ssn, TotalCharges
FROM (  
        (SELECT ssn,date,scode,dcode
         FROM outcome
        ) Z
        JOIN 
        (SELECT scode, dcode, charge, SUM(charge) TotalCharges
         FROM diagnosis
        ) U
        ON (U.scode = Z.scode AND U.dcode = Z.dcode)
     )
     GROUP BY Z.date, Z.ssn;
```

and got an error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Answer (score 1):

Why would you use so many subqueries?

```
SELECT o.date, o.ssn, SUM(d.charge)
FROM outcome o JOIN
     diagnosis d
     ON d.scode = o.scode AND d.dcode = o.dcode
GROUP BY o.date, o.ssn;
```

Your query might also work if the `GROUP BY` were in the subquery.